# ASMX Web Services: Where can I see SOAP and WSDL generating by the platform

Tags: web-services, asmx

Following reference indicates ASP.NET **automatically** creates a WSDL and SOAP request. Where or through what I can see the nuts and bolts?

http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_example.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.net generates the WSDL according to the method(WebMethod) signature along with other web service specific attributes.

For example, the method name is web service operation, serialized parameter of the method is part of SOAP request and serialized return object of the method is part of SOAP response.

Search Related topics for details,

- Building XML Web Services Using
- ASP.NET XML serialization

Answer (score 1):

Your reference is out of date. You should not use ASMX web services for new web service development. Microsoft now considers them to be "legacy technology". You should use WCF for all new web service development.

Comment: As I know, the WCF will introduce more overhead than web service, especially when first requesting it, is it?

Comment: I really don't know where you are getting your information. WCF is an implementation of web services in .NET. You seem to think that WCF is one thing, but web services are another. You're wrong. WCF is the current way to do web services in .NET, and ASMX is the legacy (old) way to do web services. I expect it to be retired some day. See http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!600A2BE4A82EA0A6!860.entry.